# Unable to run the gatling test (jvm issue)

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling

I am trying to run the gatling test on MacOS.
Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
scala version: 2.12.12
sbt version :1.4.4

I am unable to run my tests because of this error. I have tried changing the java versions(recommended one) and tried reinstalling the sbt as well.

The error log is as follows:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'AggressiveOpts'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
[error] Could not accept connection from test agent: class java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
[error] java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
[error]         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.endAccept(NioSocketImpl.java:689)
[error]         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.accept(NioSocketImpl.java:762)
[error]         at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:684)
[error]         at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.platformImplAccept(ServerSocket.java:650)
[error]         at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:626)
[error]         at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:583)
[error]         at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:540)
[error]         at sbt.ForkTests$Acceptor$1$.run(ForkTests.scala:71)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I would appreciate your feedback on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way you're using Java 8 as indicated, as your stacktrace clearly shows Jigsaw modules (`java.base/`). You're using Java 9 or older.

What happens is that the test forked JVM crashes on boot because it's being passed the `AggressiveOpts` option that was dropped after Java 8.

This option was removed in recent versions of Gatling's sbt plugin, meaning that you're using an older version.

In short: update your sbt plugin version.

Comment: do you mean to say sbt plugin version for my  IDE? Sorry I am not much familiar with this.

Comment: No, I mean your version of the https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/sbt_plugin/